# How to find the distance between a point and a line programatically?

Tags: swift, math

I found something similar that gave me the general form of a line but after writing it out I came across some limitations with horizontal/vertical lines. Source here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/637922/how-can-i-find-coefficients-a-b-c-given-two-points

I'm not that good with math but I assume there are restrictions of the general equation of a line formula and attempting to calculate the distance with the distance formula using general coefficients of A,B,C did not work out.

Here's my original code that got the coefficients.

```swift
func computeEquationOfALineCoefficients(point1: CGPoint, point2: CGPoint) -> [CGFloat] {
    // Computes the equation of a line in the form Ax + By + C = 0 thorugh
    // y - y1 = (y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1) * (x - x1) or alternatively
    // (y1-y2) * x + (x2-x1) * y + (x1-x2)*y1 + (y2-y1)*x1 = 0
    // where a = y1 - y2, b = x2 - x1, c = (x1-x2)*y1 + (y2-y1)*x1
    let x1: CGFloat = point1.x
    let x2: CGFloat = point2.x
    let y1: CGFloat = point1.y
    let y2: CGFloat = point2.y

    let A = y1 - y2
    let B = x2 - x1
    let C = (x1 - x2) * y1 + (y2 - y1) * x1

    return [A, B, C]
}
```

and then the distance formula I was using

```swift
func computeDistanceBetweenPointAndLine(point: CGPoint, A: Float, B: Float, C: Float) -> Float {
    let x: Float = Float(point.x)
    let y: Float = Float(point.y)

    let distance = abs(A * x + B * y + C) / (pow(A, 2) + pow(B, 2)).squareRoot()

    return distance
}
```

it works fine until I introduce a horizontal line like the coordinates 0,0 and 150,0.

So I then decided to try the route with the perpendicular intersection between a point and a line but I'm stumped at solving for x by setting two equations equal to each other. I found a resource for that here: https://sciencing.com/how-to-find-the-distance-from-a-point-to-a-line-13712219.html but I am not sure how this is supposed to be represented in code.

Any tips or resources I may have yet to find are appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849211/shortest-distance-between-a-point-and-a-line-segment

Comment: awesome! @matt thanks! It looks like I can solve this now :]

Comment: Yay! You'll have to translate of course.